# Laravel 4: Restrict Access to Views Based on Permissions

Tags: laravel-4, filter, laravel-routing

I am building a series of forms in Laravel 4 with Doctrine 2. I want to be able to restrict access to each forms subsystem based on a user's level of permission (none, view, view and edit, view edit and delete).

In my database I have a table where each form subsection is stored (id, form_name, view_foldername) called "libForms". I also have a "users" table with all of the typical user information. When a new user is added, a third table, "permissions" gets populated with an access level of '0' (none) for each form currently in the system for that particular user.

When a new form is created, I also have it set up to where a new directory is created in the app/views directory. The name of this directory is a camelCase version of the form's name.

**What I want to do is restrict access to any view within app/views/folderName for users that have an access level of '0' (none).** Any user without access should be spit back to the homepage.

So far I have come up with trying something like:

```
Route::filter('formAuth', function()
{
$entityManager = App::make('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface');


//get current user
$current_user = $entityManager->getRepository('User')->find(Session::get('my_userid'));

//check user's permission level for this section of forms
$form_route = $entityManager->getRepository('LibForm')->findOneBy(array('route_name' => Request::segment(1)));

...
});
```

And then calling this filter in the Controller's constructor.

```
$this->beforeFilter('formAuth');
```

I don't assume any of this is close to being correct and I am just confusing myself even more every time I think of something else!

Comment: Try to restrict the method/route that generates the output  instead of `view`.

Comment: Good call. I'm still not sure I'm going about this the right way but that's probably the correct solution to the way I asked the question.